# Android Jelly Bean - Download and install Download Manager without a pc

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, download-manager

I'm writing this from the tablet having the issue.

2 months ago when I still had a working pc I wanted to install Linux on my tablet and in the process I wiped mostly everything from it and changed the custom recovery to not include those wiped app files.

I wanted to put Android back, but I forgot to download and install the missing app files for it to work correctly, the most important being the Download Manager.

Today my pc unfortunately broke up and I have a project to be done. So I thought to begin using this tablet to program as I have no money to buy another pc for maybe a year.

The problem is that I can't download anything as I'm missing the Download Manager app. When I try to download something for ex. with Chrome it crashes.

Now, given that I have no access to a pc for a year or so but my tablet is fully rooted, is there a way to download and install the Download Manager apk?

My thoughts on possible theoretical ways:

1. As I can't download but copy/paste text from the net, I could try to look for the Download Manager apk, copy its source, paste it on text file and give it the .apk extension.
2. Trick the Chrome cache to store the .apk file and then retrieve it from the cache offline. But here I don't know where the Chrome cache is stored and I'm afraid it's in a privileged part of the system where only a file manager with root functionality can see it.
   2.
3. If it's supported create a script on Jsfiddle to fetch the apk file and save it through IndexedDB or LocalStorage and access it offline thereby being able to install it.

My question here is: Would that work? Otherwise have you ideas on how to do that given the current situation?

Comment: Does the Play Store work with the tablet in this state?

Comment: #1 definitely will *not* work, as `.apk` files are "compiled programs" (to put it in easy words; it's "binary code" you cannot simply copy/paste). #2 implies Chrome is loading the file in the first place, which it obviously does not. I can't say anything to #3. Dan's approach is the most promising; if you can access the command line, you could also try `wget <url>` to download the `.apk`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clarifications. I managed to download ADM (Advanced Download Manager) from the SlideME market that I luckily didn't wipe from the tablet. From there on I downloaded all missing apps files and got it working normally :) I can finally start hacking away!